# Substract 15 Minutes from time using Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I thought this was going to be very simple but I am really out of options now. I want to substract 15 minutes from a given time.

Example 
My time is 15:04 I want to substract 15 minutes to be 14:49. I have searched for solutions on the internet but there is no perl module that can help me out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year   => 1,
    month  => 1,
    day    => 1,
    hour   => 15, 
    minute => 4,
);  

$dt->subtract(minutes => 15);
printf "%d:%d\n", $dt->hour, $dt->minute; # prints 14:49
```

Comment: And if he's just concerned about time and not dates, he can try [Time::Clock](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Clock)

Comment: I think the above will have solved my problem, the ones below are not using the format I want but the helped me learn a lot. I was able to answer it the following way

sub subTime{
 my ($time) = @_;
 my @splittime = split(':', $time);
 my $hour =  $splittime[0];
 my $min = $splittime[1];
 if($min < 15){
 $min=($min+60)-15;
 $hour-=1;
 }else{
  $min = $min-15;
 }
 return "$hour:$min";
 
}

I call this function and its returned the substracted time. Thanks

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl for string -> `DateTime`.

Answer (score 7):

Well it all depends on how your time is stored. I prefer to use a `time_t` as returned by the `time` built in.

```
my $now = time();
my $before1 = $now - (15*60);      # 15 minutes ago
my $before2 = $now - (3*60*60);    # 3 hours ago
my $before3 = $now - (2*24*60*60); # 2 days ago
```

For output I use the `POSIX` module

```
print POSIX::strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %T', localtime($before1) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MClass::Date -e 'my $d=Class::Date->new("2011-07-13 15:04:00"); my $d2 = $d-"15m"; print $d2, "\n";'
```

Output:

2011-07-13 14:49:00

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod)

```
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_DHMS); 

($year2, $month2, $day2, $h2, $m2, $s2) = 
Add_Delta_DHMS( $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $days_offset, $hour_offset, $minute_offset, $second_offset );

($y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S) = Add_Delta_DHMS(Today_and_Now(), 0, 0, -15, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the time to unix time, for example the current time: `$unixtime = time();` then subtract 15*60 from it then convert to a nice string with something like

```
sub display_time {
  my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,undef,undef,undef) = localtime(time);
  $year += 1900;
  $mon += 1;
  return "$year.".sprintf("%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",$mon,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sub-routine if you are only concerned about time not date:

```
sub subTime{
    my ($time) = @_;
    my @splittime = split(':', $time);
    my $hour = $splittime[0];
    my $min = $splittime[1];
    if($min < 15){
        $min=($min+60)-15; 
        $hour-=1;
    }
    else{
        $min = $min-15;
    } 
    return "$hour:$min";
}
```

---

**Disclamer:** This was the solution OP used, he mentioned it in comments in above answer (in @eugene's answer).