# How to parse a string into a DateTime object in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, datetime

I know about the `DateTime` Perl module, and many of the [`DateTime::Format::`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime%3A%3AFormat&mode=all) modules to parse specific kinds of date/time formats. However given some examples of date/time strings, how can I figure out (at coding/design time, *not* at runtime) which specific module should I use?

For example, I want to parse strings like: `October 28, 2011 9:00 PM PDT`

Is there a list somewhere of the most common date/time formats where I could look this up and find which would be the most suitable module?

I also know about some modules which try to "guess" the format for each given string at runtime and do their best. But, for sensitive applications, I would like to determine (as strictly as possible) the format first when designing an application, and then use a module which will warn me if a string does not match the specified format.

How should I go about this?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't reliably parse time zone abbreviations. Take [CST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) for example.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) takes date/time strings and parses them into DateTime objects.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z',
  on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime('October 28, 2011 9:00 PM PDT');

print "$dt\n";
```

The character sequences used in the pattern are POSIX standard. See 'man strftime' for details.

Comment: Thanks! This is why ended up doing in the end. Still, I would love to see a list of common or standard date formats (ISO, RFC) to check if some particular strings I have would fit any of those.

Comment: There's an (out of date) list of DateTime modules (which include a number of DT::Format modules) at http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/Modules

Comment: Not a big fan of having to specify the format to so precisely

Comment: Is parsing time zone abbreviations [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl/7488148#comment130166102_7486470)?

Answer (score 36):

I tend to use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) simply because it's part of the standard Perl module set since version [5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perldelta.html#New-modules).

You can't beat it's ability to [parse date strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing).

```
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime(
      "October 28, 2011 9:00 PM PDT",
      "%B %d, %Y %r %Z");
```

Comment: Sadly, it is not part of the standard Perl module set in version 5.8 (which is still the highest version you can run on RHEL 5.x).  It is in 5.14 though.

Comment: "which is still the highest version you can run on RHEL 5.x". That's just not true. It's true that RHEL 5.x comes with Perl 5.8.8 as standard. But there's nothing at all preventing you from building a more recent version.

Comment: @DaveCross There's a certain point Chirs makes. It's not always possible to install a newer release of Perl outside of RPM. RHEL machines are usually in corporate production environments (otherwise, you'd run Fedora or Centos). These systems will usually not have the complete set of _developer tools_ such as the C compiler installed on them, you might not have the access on them in order to install tools, and even if you could, the people who run the production environment may look down on someone installing an unofficial version of Perl on the production environment.

Comment: @DavidW: I can't argue with any of that. But that's all a long way from saying that you **can't** run anything newer than 5.8.8. Technically, there's nothing stopping you. Politically, there may well be.

Comment: Thanks for bringing [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to my attention! Great module. E.g. if you want to output the weekday in an exotic language you can write `my $day = Time::Piece->strptime($isod, "%Y-%m-%d")->day(qw/Sonntag Montag Dienstag Mittwoch Donnerstag Freitag Samstag /);`

Comment: I'm using ActivePerl 5.12.2, and the example in this answer doesn't work for me; it says "Runtime error: Error parsing time". If I change "PDT" to "GMT", then it works. Are you sure that "PDT" is a valid time zone to specify here?

Comment: @TannerSwett If you're using ActiveState Perl that probably means you're on Windows. Only starting with `Time::Piece-1.17` the internal `strptime` implementation is used [across all the platforms](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/commit/390a130#diff-bbd4b6a86bc65b6ac8e79e97afc61499158edb40f7bb404c70637b46d80a7ad2R5-R6). That might explain why it worked for the author of the answer. These days it doesn't work that way particularly on Linux...

Comment: ...If possible parsing time zone abbreviations should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl#comment130166102_7486470). In case you're working with local timestamps (not arbitrary time zones) though, you can use the [`localtime->strptime("...", "...%Z"` trick](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/issues/52#issuecomment-1246310525). More on creating `Time::Piece` objects [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4aa50308bab6bb41c5c8dd8ebdc7defb).

Comment: Just tried this in Cygwin using Perl 5.32.1 and Time::Piece 1.3401. I get the same failure as @TannerSwett . However, the example from the module's documentation works: `my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("Sunday 3rd Nov, 1943", "%A %drd %b, %Y");`. Source: https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at the [`Date::Parse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) module, i.e. the `str2time()` function. It has support for [most of the commonly used formats](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse#EXAMPLE-DATES).

Example:

```
use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;

my $str = "Tue, 20 Sep 2011 08:51:08 -0500";
my $epoch = str2time($str);
my $datetime = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is precisely *not* what I want to do. I don't want the function to guess the format of the string; I want to be able to specify the format which the code should expect with precision.

Comment: Nice, that is precisely what I do want to do :-) I'll recommend a format but if someone varies it then it will be best effort.

Comment: Actually that module doesn't appear to be that good. It resolves 15/4/2015 to 1429060633 but 15/apr/2015 to 1429020000. It's hard to imagine what it is even doing here as that is 11.28 hrs difference parsing dates only. There should be no time component.

Comment: Had some bugs for non-american date format. Don't useful for my date format(30/10/2000). **BUGS** _When both the month and the date are specified in the date as numbers they are always parsed assuming that the month number comes before the date. This is the usual format used in American dates._ [Link to documentation "BUGS" section](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse#BUGS)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for common date/time formats 
have a look at [DateTime::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Locale-0.45/lib/DateTime/Locale.pm#Creating_a_completely_new_locale)

```
use DateTime::Locale
my $locale = DateTime::Locale->load('DE_de');
```

> The following methods return strings appropriate for the DateTime->format_cldr() method:
>
> ```
> $locale->date_format_full()
> $locale->date_format_long()
> $locale->date_format_medium()
> $locale->date_format_short()
> $locale->date_format_default()
> $locale->time_format_full()
> $locale->time_format_long()
> $locale->time_format_medium()
> $locale->time_format_short()
> $locale->time_format_default()
> $locale->datetime_format_full()
> $locale->datetime_format_long()
> $locale->datetime_format_medium()
> $locale->datetime_format_short()
> $locale->datetime_format_default()
> ```

You can parse Dates with the [DateTime::Format::CLDR](http://search.cpan.org/~maros/DateTime-Format-CLDR-1.13/lib/DateTime/Format/CLDR.pm) module

```
use DateTime::Format::CLDR;
# 1. Basic example
my $cldr = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
    pattern     => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    locale      => 'de_DE',
    time_zone   => 'Europe/Berlin',
);
my $dt = $cldr->parse_datetime('26.06.2013 11:05:28');
```

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime::Format::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Natural) is also a good candidate.

Test:

```
perl -MDateTime::Format::Natural \
-E "my $d=DateTime::Format::Natural->new->parse_datetime('October 11, 2021'); say $d->month;"

10
```