# perl: calculating duration between timestamps

Tags: perl

I have a series of string pairs

```
$str1 = '2016-09-29 10:02:29';
$str2 = '2016-09-29 10:05:45';
```

the first string is always before the second
I would like to calucate how much seconds have passed between the two timestamps

the above would be 196 seconds

is there a quick way to calculate the difference between two timestamps?

(obsolete) Update: I wrote the following code and i m getting this error

```
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   format    => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'UTC',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

The following parameter was passed in the call to DateTime::Format::Strptime::new but was not listed in the validation options: format
 at /usr/software/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm line 130.
    DateTime::Format::Strptime::new(undef, 'format', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 'time_zone', 'UTC', 'on_error', 'croak') called at ./show_startup.pl line 150
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string into a DateTime object in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate; this question doesn't require DateTime objects per se.

Comment: ... and the linked post doesn't at all refer to how to get distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) (and [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime)):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $str1 = '2016-09-29 10:02:29';
my $str2 = '2016-09-29 10:05:45';

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',  # If they are local time timestamps
      -or-
   time_zone => 'UTC',    # If they are UTC timestamps
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime($str1);
my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime($str2);

my $seconds = $dt2->delta_ms($dt1)->in_units('seconds');
```

---

Using [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Piece):

```
use Time::Piece qw( localtime );

my $str1 = '2016-09-29 10:02:29';
my $str2 = '2016-09-29 10:05:45';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);  # If they are UTC timestamps
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, $format);  # 
  -or-
my $t1 = localtime->strptime($str1, $format);    # If they are local time timestamps
my $t2 = localtime->strptime($str2, $format);    #

my $seconds = ($t2 - $t1)->seconds;
```

Comment: Note that the `localtime->strptime(...)` form is undocumented and not officially supported.

Comment: @melpomene, Half right. It's true that this crucial piece of T::P isn't documented -- feel free to submit a patch -- but this functionality is explicitly supported. Personally, I despise the module.

Comment: What do you mean by explicitly supported?

Comment: There's code whose sole purpose to support this functionality.

Comment: You could argue that, but that might be a leftover experiment and removed in a future release (that's why I don't like peeking at the source and relying on implementation details). But I did find something else: There's a test that calls `localtime->strptime`. Now I like it much better.

Comment: after looking at http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.68/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm, i've changed to patttern instead of format and it seems to work now

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module, which comes with Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $str1 = '2016-09-29 10:02:29';
my $str2 = '2016-09-29 10:05:45';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, $format);

my $seconds = ($t2 - $t1)->seconds;
print "Result: $seconds\n";
```

This code doesn't take the local timezone into account, i.e. it assumes the times are in UTC.

Comment: This will give the wrong answer if the time stamps are local times.