# Search for a string and save the searched string in array using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a  huge file which has data and iam trying to search a string in each line.
and just save that search part and not entire line in array.

Here is the code i have tried

```
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $start_run = time();

    while (<DATA>){
        my $line=$_  ;
        if ($line =~ m/Date/) {
           my @result = grep (/Date/, $line);
           print @result;
       }
     }


#####
my $end_run = time();
my $run_time = sprintf "%.2f", (($end_run - $start_run) / 60);
print "Elapsed: $run_time minutes\n";


__DATA__
ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xbian.dbaas.ing.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDI)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx0))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MUXFO_1_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-29 08:58:10
insert into MX_FN_OWNER.TRN_EDBF (TIMESTAMP,M_IDENTITY,M_REFERENCE,M_USER,M_GROUP,M_DESK,M_DATE_SYS,M_DATE_CMP,M_TIME_CMP,M_SDATE_CMP,M_STIME_CMP,M_COMMENT,M_ERROR,M_START_END,M_TIME_CPU,M_TIME_SYB,M_TIME_ELAP,M_SCRPT_NAME,M_UNIT_NAME,M_ERR_COUNT,M_NPID) values (0,TRN_EODA_DBFS.nextval,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19) (Bulk_Copy begin, 19 columns, 1 Flush size)

                              ==============================================
ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xb305-scan.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx02fn))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MXFO_168991_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-29 09:21:10
Mux execution time: 00:00:00   3 ms
```

Apparently each line has Date and i am just interested in Date  and the time it has sp that i can substract the time between 2 lines and save it .
But when i am trying to grep the output is entire line . i could not split the line as there is no delimiter .

Is there a way i can just get the Date : 2020-03-29 09:21:10 associated with each line

> Conversion Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => 'd{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',
  on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime('2020-03-29 08:58:10');

print "$dt\n";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could match a date like pattern and use `\K` to reset the match buffer.

Note that the pattern does not validate the date time itself.

Then add the whole match using `$&` to an array.

```
\bDate:\h+\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `\bDate:\h+\K` Match `Date:` and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars.
- `\K` Reset match buffer
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` Match a date time like pattern
- `$` If the value is always at the end, you can assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tuzXfM/1) | [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##tVRtb9pIEP7Orxjl4GSrhtqkpGF7js6xl6vV2kbrpS26VCtjlsY6MMgvLbkq99dzs@alRO2HtlJXsB7PPDPPzOyON7JYDh4e6lJCWRVZWr1oKflTUuRZ/qH81puXVAkhXr3ayGKn4dlKEjLOZCpPFbFM1/kcvVqrO/gzKRD96TZbStD@8BzuXOmfW4ALje1llku7LQBeNKpsAVqjA/s/WD29mSGnJDe3T25e3cw/P7vv4t7f70qrnuRkbz/VYRdcrU1d3mqK34D27/qO4b5132ot1kXDnoFmQq8H7d8QdPBUOchtVlal1kb134h6AtZ7/TSyck7ropB5pTJUZYN92o7uFXZ1U6FCOzqptY/43nikPetMu51VtzOHzkvSCUgnPtuneyDL5fbnmJrcf4TtEe08WyyQ7jF996vav3hviiyvtMave7XK8rqSJfTgDPbygen@SIfHIYS6FkK0Yll8lEWYYHGgeTR2mT/mfhTamhuFIXW54H5Aowm3L0xdY5SzqXCjScjtga45nsdoHNvamEU8cqPXNnfHuvYyirm9nWVJ3pvPkqTs4YXu5bLStXHEuG31LV0/hld52FpM2RvKbI96vt68@C4VoRNQe7PamjrehF2i/G6DiUZFki530zFLSrnLPngnRqGI3oaUAfOug9hJU1mWBEKH@2@oiFwf3HWey7TK1vneZ2uKYPJuFAlLWKfWNQELoBkF6Jt9s2ued/tDMC/J4JJYZivLS1lUgJ1fnxL3OAsF9a5HoKm2xdwJxkYgfI@G3OdTFBkdUUZDl6I8wULx8ReLJgqF3X@lHg6nIp7GB9FtQqhwezE@UccnejcKAuRBiTIWscbqMC5o6B0DjCcHMZ5eH0T62mliuWzMm6ar3EL/KGO43ZmjHI59T4ePybLGW6aZRlNw5DkCi4576tKizSCWQfoGOTfIM4MMDHJhkOcGuTTIEE0m/tFuIcBChIUQCzEWgixEWQizhjpo1/XyH@GuN3cwkx@y3ABrCOl6Wa/yEmUYLfFbA2X2r9Rbj4bt62X/0PqVM3FuDrplioPx3ePg4mF735iJ/iL/tWPRTMXF5XD4naMxJH1LjUZQb0FuZVorNKivJAHTJM0Pz@IcViU8PPwP)

For example:

```
my @arr;
while (<DATA>){
    my $line=$_  ;
    if ($line =~ m/\bDate:\h+\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/) {
        push(@arr, $&);
    }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#arr) {
    if (exists($arr[$i + 1])) {
        my $currentDateTime = Time::Piece->strptime(
            $arr[$i],
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        my $nextDateTime = Time::Piece->strptime(
            $arr[$i + 1],
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

        my $diff = $nextDateTime - $currentDateTime;
        print($diff->minutes);
    }        
}
```

Output

```
23 minutes
```

You could narrow down the date pattern using ranges (It still does not validate it)

```
\bDate:\h+\K\d{4}-(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])-(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\h+(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l20bv2/1)

Comment: wow, thats works, thanks . Assuming there are 1 million lines and each line has dates and i would want to calculate elapsed time between 2 lines . Saving all dates in array and substracting time would work, is that the correct approach?

Comment: ex 09:21 - 08:58 = 23 minutes from the above 2 lines, like wise i would want to calculate elapsed time between all the lines one by one

Comment: You could for example loop the array and parse the format to a [DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl) for the current entry and the next entry. Then perform you calculations.

Comment: hi , i have tried the below, but it doesnt work , may be i have messed up the pattern. i have updated the code with new conversion code. please let me know

Comment: oh , i did not notice that you have updated the code..thanks a ton

Comment: @Sai I have updated the answer with an example to get the diff.

Comment: what if the diffrence is hours, it shows 0 , i tried $diff->hours : $diff->minutes , but it fails, will try printing entire $diff and see whats in the hash :)

Comment: The difference is 23 minutes and hours is 0. If you increase the difference of the date and time, you will see the hours.

Comment: Regarding \K Reset match buffer , why do we have to reset buffer and whats importance of it

Comment: The reason is that the pattern initially matches `Date:` and a space, but you don't want that to be part of the match. That is why you could use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and continue matching from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $start_time=time();

my @arr;
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
  on_error => 'croak',
);
while (<DATA>)
{
   my $line=$_;
   if($line =~ m/\bDate:\h+\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/) {
      push (@arr,$&);
   }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#arr) {
    if (exists($arr[$i + 1])) {
        my $currentDateTime =  $parser->parse_datetime ($arr[$i]);
        my $nextDateTime =  $parser->parse_datetime ($arr[$i + 1]);
        my $diff = $nextDateTime - $currentDateTime;
        print($diff->hours,":",$diff->minutes );
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved with following algorithm:

Extract data by looking through data for pattern `\bDate: \S+ \S+$` into an array.

Pass data array to subroutine which computes differences between elements and return reference to result array (elements of array represent hash with keys `hours,minutes`).

Output result array content

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my @data;
my $re = qr/\bDate: (\S+ \S+)$/;

/$re/ && push @data,$1 for <DATA>;

say "$_->{hours}:$_->{minutes}" for @{ time_diff(\@data) };

sub time_diff {
    my $data = shift;
    my @result;

    my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
      on_error => 'croak',
    );

    for (1..$#data) {
        my $begin = $parser->parse_datetime ( $data->[$_-1] );
        my $end   = $parser->parse_datetime ( $data->[$_]   );
        my $diff  = $end-$begin;

        push @result, { hours => $diff->hours, minutes => $diff->minutes };
    }

    return \@result;
}

__DATA__
ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xbian.dbaas.ing.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDI)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx0))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MUXFO_1_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-29 08:58:10
insert into MX_FN_OWNER.TRN_EDBF (TIMESTAMP,M_IDENTITY,M_REFERENCE,M_USER,M_GROUP,M_DESK,M_DATE_SYS,M_DATE_CMP,M_TIME_CMP,M_SDATE_CMP,M_STIME_CMP,M_COMMENT,M_ERROR,M_START_END,M_TIME_CPU,M_TIME_SYB,M_TIME_ELAP,M_SCRPT_NAME,M_UNIT_NAME,M_ERR_COUNT,M_NPID) values (0,TRN_EODA_DBFS.nextval,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19) (Bulk_Copy begin, 19 columns, 1 Flush size)

                              ==============================================
ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xb305-scan.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx02fn))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MXFO_168991_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-29 09:21:10
Mux execution time: 00:00:00   3 ms 

ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xb305-scan.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx02fn))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MXFO_168991_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-30 07:11:05
Mux execution time: 00:00:00   3 ms

ServerName: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=5)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xb305-scan.net)(PORT=121))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=pmx02fn))) ServerType: Oracle DatabaseName: MX_FN_OWNER RDBMSAccess: NATIVE_OCI ConnectionName: Mx0_MXFO_168991_1 ConnectionNo: 1  Date: 2020-03-30 21:49:42
Mux execution time: 00:00:00   3 ms
```

Output

```
0:23
21:49
14:38
```